# Number of values in tableA not in tableB?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA 
(
    accountNumber, --has colons in between values... need to be removed on join
    type, --(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
    status1,
    status2
);
CREATE TABLE tableB 
(
    accountNumber,
    usage, -- [0,inf)
    day_id
);
```

I would like to know how many accountNumbers are in tableA that are NOT in tableB. I have constructed two ways to do this:
**Way #1**

```
with cteA as (

Select upper(replace(accountNumber, ':',''))) as accountNumber,
       type
from tableA
where status1 = 'Active'
and status2 = 'Active'
and type in ('1','2','3','4')
),
cteB as (
Select distinct accountNumber 
from tableB
where usage > 0 
and day_id > '2022-01-01'
),
cte as (
Select a.accountNumber,
       b.accountNumber,
       a.type
from tableA a
left join tableB b 
on a.accountNumber = b.accountNumber
where b.accountNumber is null)
select type, count(*)
from cte
group by 1
order by 2 desc;
```

**Way #2**

```
select type,
       count(distinct accountNumber),
       count(distinct accountNumber) filter (where upper(replace(accountNumber,':','')) in (select accountNumber from tableB where day_id > '2022-01-01' and usage > 0))
from tableA
where status1 = 'Active'
and status2 = 'Active'
and type in ('1','2','3','4')
group by 1
```

As far as I can tell, these should give me the same answer. Granted, way 2 requires me doing a subtraction (manually in excel or in my head)... but I don't see why these queries would give me a different value? Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you please post sample data?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, than there should be much easier ways.
How about:

```
select count(distinct accountNumber)
from tableA
where not exists(select 1 from tableB where tableA.accountNumber = tableB.accountNumber)
```